# Deprecated policy 'create_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat' in Neutron without provided alternative

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

when I try to customize my policy for neutron, I encountered a problem:

```
2023-12-12 22:31:47.840 31668 WARNING oslo_policy.policy [None req-b27a6bef-0a7a-4536-b99d-cbfcb79a791c - - - - - -] Policies ['update_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat', 'create_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat'] reference a rule that is not defined.
```

The file `policy.yaml` in `/etc/neutron/` is:

```yaml
# /etc/neutron/policy.yaml

update_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat: "rule:admin_or_member"
create_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat: "rule:admin_or_member"
```

This content is from my searching result in [Official Documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/2023.2/configuration/policy.html)

Then, I searched for another official documentation of **sample policy file** (https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/2023.2/configuration/policy-sample.html), it said:

```yaml
# Specify ``enable_snat`` in ``external_gateway_info`` information
# when creating a router
# POST  /routers
# Intended scope(s): project
#"create_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat": "rule:admin_only"

# DEPRECATED
# "create_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat":"rule:admin_only"
# has been deprecated since W in favor of
# "create_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat":"rule:admin_only".
# The router API now supports system scope and default roles.
```

```yaml
# Update ``enable_snat`` attribute of ``external_gateway_info``
# information of a router
# PUT  /routers/{id}
# Intended scope(s): project
#"update_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat": "rule:admin_only"

# DEPRECATED
# "update_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat":"rule:admin_only"
# has been deprecated since W in favor of
# "update_router:external_gateway_info:enable_snat":"rule:admin_only".
# The router API now supports system scope and default roles.
```

It said that this policy is **deprecated** in 2023.2 (My OpenStack version is 2023.2 (Bobcat Version)). But it didn't tell me what I should use, the solution that appears to offer an alternative **is actually the exact same** one that was deprecated.

---

**So what should I do if I want to customize my policy in Neutron?** I would like to *allow* the **member**s in any projects to create a router with SNAT function.

Thank you for your time and help and I would greatly appreciate any advice on this issue.

---

Other Information:

- OpenStack Version: 2023.2 (Bobcat)
- Operating System: Rocky Linux 9.3
- Deployment Tools used: PackStack (For Proof of concept and testing purpose) [All In One Deployment]
- **I restarted the neutron-server service** for each attempt to modify the policy file.